# Web api Post call from ajax fails

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have an web api wand I call it method in an ajax with POST method, sending the parameter as data . It gives me a 404 not found error.

But when I pass the data in the query string , it works fine. Please help me fixing the matter and get it worked when calling the method with data in the body, not the query string.

**Note : The web application and Web-api are running on different ports**

**Sending a concrete type object in query string also does not work and received to web api as null**

config

```
<httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, contentType, data" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Controller

```
 public class RiskController : ApiController
    {
```

method

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
    public DashboardContainerViewModel GetDashboardContainer(string token)
    {
```

Ajax call

```
var postData = { token: priv.secToken };        

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:48060/api/Risk/GetDashboardContainer',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                pub.dashboardHeader(data.Name);
                var defaultTab = _.find(data.Dashboards, function (tab) {
                    return tab.IsDefault == true;
                });
```

And I get POST http://localhost:48060/api/Risk/GetDashboardContainer 404 (Not Found)

Fiddler request headers

```
POST http://localhost:48060/api/Risk/GetDashboardContainer HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:48060
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 142
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:10452
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:10452/Authorised/DashBoard/DashBoard.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

token=ETvgg0YH4sx9w%2FiQL5560S20Ja4jGix%2FiBTOFGpQCliYZVilmtKiXPbk30d8FTYbhUWyFqz8%2FqT1pmI0oY6rzDGQ7krL6d2fDKDKwJhfCNFXZxnv%2BPCUj5ki5eizdWOM
```

Fiddler response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGVmYXVsdENvbGxlY3Rpb25cQ0FNTVNfUHJvZHVjdHNcX1JlbGVhc2VcMTQxMExSLUFNXFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlXENBTU1TLlNBQVMuV2ViQVBJXENBTU1TLlNBQVMuSVJNV2ViQVBJXGFwaVxSaXNrXEdldERhc2hib2FyZENvbnRhaW5lcg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, contentType, data
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:47:22 GMT
Content-Length: 215

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:48060/api/Risk/GetDashboardContainer'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Risk' that matches the request."}
```

Comment: did you try to adding [FromBody] before the parameter, but remmber that HTTPGet doesn't have body so it will by default look at the query string.

Answer (score 0):

This is most lilkely due to a routing error in my opinion and experience, have you tried looking at RouteConfig.cs to make sure it sets the right routes for your API?
Something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );



}
```

Comment: If you could provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would be great to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller method uses simple type parameter. WebApi will search for simple parameter in request URL. So if you want to POST parameter, you must tell WebApi to look at the request body.

```
public DashboardContainerViewModel GetDashboardContainer([FromBody] string token)
```

But you also need to change the format of data you are sending. Simple type data sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` must be in format `'=value'` not `'token=value'`

```
var postData = "=testData";
```